# I want the bootstrap collapse when one will expand the other will close

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried this code it's work for me, but the problem is that when ever I use this code in Angular the code is getting error in jquery that "collapse tag is not found in jquery".why this happen can anyone help me to solve this problem....?

```js
$('.button-click').click( function(e) {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <a class="btn btn-primary button-click" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>
 
   <a class="btn btn-primary button-click" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery in combination with Angular is not the proper way to go. Instead, use Angular powered Bootstrap such as [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) to avoid such issues inherently.

***Note:** In Bootstrap 5, which is currently in alpha, [jQuery will be dropped](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/08/bootsrap-5-drops-jquery/) anyway.*

Using Angular powered Bootstrap with `ng-bootstrap`, you have two options:

1. Using [`ng-bootstrap`'s collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples#basic) as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzpfy6?file=src/app/collapse-basic.html):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="!isCollapsed" (click)="isCollapsed2 = true; isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</button>
 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="!isCollapsed2" (click)="isCollapsed = true; isCollapsed2 = !isCollapsed2"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed2" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
  Link with href
</button>

<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed">
  <div class="card card-body">
    1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="collapseExample2" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    2 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you could write some fancy Angular method that replaces jQuery's `$('.collapse').collapse('hide');` as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vzpfy6-yrka2x?file=src/app/collapse-basic.ts).

```
public isCollapsed = [false, true];
resetAllCollapsedAndToggleCurrent (index) {
  this.isCollapsed.forEach((item, collapseIndex) => {
    if (index === collapseIndex) {
      this.isCollapsed[index] = !this.isCollapsed[index];
    } else {
      this.isCollapsed[collapseIndex] = true;
    }
  })
}
```

... with this html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="!isCollapsed[0]" (click)="resetAllCollapsedAndToggleCurrent(0)"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed[0]" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</button>
 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [class.active]="!isCollapsed[1]" (click)="resetAllCollapsedAndToggleCurrent(1)"
          [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed[1]" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
  Link with href
</button>

<div id="collapseExample" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed[0]">
  <div class="card card-body">
    1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="collapseExample2" [ngbCollapse]="isCollapsed[1]">
  <div class="card card-body">
    2 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

2. A *similar* (collapse all is not possible) behavior that you are describing is presented by [tabset pills](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabset/examples#pills), which you could easily transfer to your example as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcks4j?file=src/app/tabset-pills.html):

```
<ngb-tabset type="pills">
  <ngb-tab title="Link with href">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>1 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Link with href">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>2 Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

Good luck!